# Spark pairRDD not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark

> value `subtractByKey` is not a member of
>   **org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, LabeledPoint)]**
>
> value `join` is not a member of **org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,
>   LabeledPoint)]**

How come this is happening? **org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, LabeledPoint)]** is *pair-value RDD* and I already imported `import org.apache.spark.rdd._`

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: @CarlosVilchez For some weird reason, I have to create a PairRDDFunctions object out of the original key value pair. Maybe it is because the interface has changed. Because the new PairRDDFunctions is defined as RDD[K, V] but not defined as RDD[(k,v)]. However the other RDD has to be RDD[(k,v)]. Anyway, it is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the spark-shell, this works exactly as expected, without having to `import` anything:

```
scala> case class LabeledPoint(x: Int, y: Int, label: String)
defined class LabeledPoint

scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List("this","is","a","test")).map(label => (label, LabeledPoint(0,0,label)))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, LabeledPoint)] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:23

scala> val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List("this","is","a","test")).map(label => (label, 1))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:21

scala> rdd1.join(rdd2)
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (LabeledPoint, Int))] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at join at <console>:28
```

Comment: For some weird reason, I have to create a PairRDDFunctions object out of the original key value pair. Maybe it is because the interface has changed. Because the new PairRDDFunctions is defined as RDD[K, V]  but not defined as RDD[(k,v)]. However the other RDD has to be RDD[(k,v)]. Anyway, it is solved. Thanks